# Finite pro-$ p $ subgroups of $ {\rm SL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}[[T]]) $

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, linear-groups

Let $ p $ be an odd prime, $ \mathbb{F} $ a finite field of characterisitc $ p $ and $ \mathbb{F}[[T]] $ the formal power series over $ \mathbb{F} $. Let $ G $ be a pro-$ p $ subgroup of $ {\rm SL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}[[T]]) $.

**Questions:**

1. Suppose that $ G $ is a non-solvable infinite group. Is it true that $ G $ contains a non-solvable finite subgroup?
2. If $ G $ is torsion-free, then is true that $ G=\{1\} $?